# Find a subset $ B\subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that the function $h$ is well-defined and onto.

Tags: functions

Find a subset $ B\subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that the function:

$$h:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow B: h(m,n) = 14m + 21n $$

is well-defined and onto.

---

$h(m,n) = 14m + 21 n = 7(2m+3n) $ so if $B =\{7k, k\in \mathbb{Z}\} $ then function is $h$ is onto.

Is my answer correct  ? How do I prove $h$ is well defined?

Comment: The answer is correct, but you haven't proved that $h$ is onto. To prove that $h$ is well defined you have to show that for each $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ we have $h(m, n) \in B$ (which is rather evident from what you wrote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove surjectivity, use [Bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Since $\gcd(14,21)=7$, there exists $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $14x+21y=7$ and hence $14(kx)+21(ky)=7k=h(kx,ky)$ showing surjectivity.

---

In fact, here's a generalization:

For the map $h\colon\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to B$ where $h(m,n)=am+bn$, consider the subset $B:=\{\gcd(a,b)k\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$ for which the map $h$ is well-defined and onto.

The problem at hand has $a=14$ and $b=21$